# jQuery: use a single function instead of repeated functions for similar operations

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently I am using fancybox to display iframes like this:

```
$('#img-001').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'doc-001.html',
       showCloseButton: true
    });
});


$('#img-002').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'doc-002.html',
        showCloseButton: true
    });
});
```

However doing this is tedious and requires copying the same code over and over. Is there an alternative that would allow to use a single function? Such an operation would take whatever is `#img-ID` and change `href` to `doc-ID.html`. Or, alternatively, how to do this using a class (each element still needs a specific link)?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with a few minutes after posting (`mask` is a class that all elements share):

```
$('div.mask').click(function() {

    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var documentLink = "work-" + id.split("-")[1] + ".html";

    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: documentLink,
        showCloseButton: true
    })
}
);
```

However I'm wondering if there are better ways to handle `documentLink`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution here is

```
$('[id^="img-"]').click(function() { // select all elements whose id starts with "img-"
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'doc'+this.id.slice(3)+'.html', // takes the "-007" part of "img-007"
        showCloseButton: true
    });
});
```

Comment: This will work even with images that could not be in the intrest of the OP, even if it is very unlikely. Anyway, very elegant solution, worth +1! Just a question: is there any difference between `slice` and `substring` applied to strings?

Comment: @LightStyle I thought OP had more than 2 images. Regarding the difference between slice and substring, one is easier to type to me :)

Comment: Yes I know he will probably have more than two images, but this could bring to unexpected results(but it's very unlikely, as I said before). Regarding the difference between the two... LOL

Comment: How does this compare (honest question, as I'm very naive with JS) to the class based approach I used (see below)?

Comment: @einar If you can define a class and add it to your images, then it's faster (and maybe cleaner) than using the powerful "starts with" selector.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#img-001, #img-002').click(function() {
    var code = this.id.replace('img', '');
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'doc' + code + '.html',
        showCloseButton: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#img-001,#img-002').click(function() {
    $.fancybox({
        type: 'iframe',
        href: 'doc-'+this.id.split['-'][1]+'.html',
       showCloseButton: true
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall guide you:

```
function magic(){
    m = $(this).attr("id").match(/.*-(.*)/)
    $.fancybox({
       type: 'iframe',
       href: 'doc-'+m[1]+'.html',
       showCloseButton: true
     });
}
```

and apply to all images or whatever selector you wish:

```
$("body").find("img").each(magic);
```